# Javascript indexOf

Tags: javascript

I'm not well clued up with javascript so I'm having a problem getting the following script to work. I need to check if a name entered is also contained within a message.

```
<input type="hidden" id="Message" value="<%= rsDetail.Fields("Message") %>">
<input type="hidden" id="FirstName" value="<%= rsDetail.Fields("FirstName")%>">

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function NameCheck(){
var FirstName=document.getElementByID('FirstName');
var CardMessage=document.getElementByID('Message');
var aPosition = CardMessage.indexOf('FirstName');

if (aPosition == -1)
alert("Name Not In Message.");
}
-->
</script>

<a href="NextPage.asp" onClick="NameCheck();">Proceed</a>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById()` returns the element, not the element's value.  To get the element's value, you can do `document.getElementById('someId').value`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to get the *value* of the input `FirstName`.  `getElementById()` only returns the node itself.  Instead access its value:

```
var FirstName = document.getElementById('FirstName').value;
var CardMessage = document.getElementById('Message').value;

// Then use the variable `FirstName` instead of the quoted string
var aPosition = CardMessage.indexOf(FirstName);

// Best practice would be to use === for strict type comarison here...
if (aPosition === -1)
  alert("Name Not In Message.");
}
```

Also, note that you've misspelled `getElementById`, with a capital `D` at the end where it should be lowercase.

Comment: How would I modify the code so that I get a yes no option on the alert where yes allows the user to progress but no holds them on the page.

Comment: @Darren Cook instead of `alert()` use `confirm()` and return its value: `return confirm('Name not in message');`

Answer (score 1):

`'FirstName'` with quote is string, not the variable `FirstName`. You need:

```
// remove the quote, pass the variable FirstName instead of string 'FirstName'
var aPosition = CardMessage.indexOf(FirstName);
```

EDIT: I missed two things before. First you need to get the value of the node, and second is the uppercase D. So the correct code is:

```
var FirstName = document.getElementById('FirstName').value;
var aPosition = CardMessage.indexOf(FirstName);
```

Answer (score 1):

This what you are trying, I think.

```
var FirstName=document.getElementById('FirstName').value;
var CardMessage=document.getElementById('Message').value;
var aPosition = CardMessage.indexOf( FirstName );
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to use jQuery. Your code we can minified to max 2 line:

```
$("#click").click(function() {
    var found = $('#Message').val().indexOf($("#FirstName").val());
    console.log(found);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementByID` should be `document.getElementById`

Answer (score 0):

The `indexOf()` method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.
This method returns `-1` if the value to search for never occurs.
Note: The `indexOf()` method is case sensitive.

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
var FirstName=document.getElementByID('FirstName');
var aPosition = CardMessage.indexOf(FirstName);
```

In your exemple you are looking for the following string `FirstName` not the value of the variable `FirstName`